# RegEX: Find valid/invalid strings based on condition

Tags: regex

Trying to come up with one RegEx pattern that will find valid/invalid strings from a bunch of strings that i get in my program.

The validity of the string is found based on 2 conditions.

1. If string starts with **F** or **3** or **DC** or **9**, then it's considered invalid.
2. If string has anything other than **alphanumeric** or "**-**", then its considered invalid.

I want to combine this 2 conditions and come up with one RegEx.

Example strings:

```
WES897-JK002  // valid string

FDD2+E32FFCC  // invalid string

2WWKDFKK0091  // valid string

DCFFF45JJSSD  // invalid string

SDSD/8890012  // invalid string
```

The challenge am facing is to come up with one RegEx pattern combining both the above conditions.

So far i did this, but this doesn't look any good!

```
^(F|3|DC|9)[A-Z0-9-]+$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put the first pattern inside a negative lookahead assertion.

```
^(?!F|3|DC|9)[A-Z0-9-]+$
```

OR

simply like

```
^(?![F39]|DC)[A-Z0-9-]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sN1nN6/1)

Comment: When i test this, not able to see any matches.

Comment: @Kris if you left the `//comments` in place for your test, it won't match because it is expecting the alphanumeric string to end at the end of the line.